# How to run docker container in production in Centos?

Tags: docker, background, daemon

So on my server, I run my docker container as a daemon process via:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -td example
```

It seems to work fine - for now!

But, what if I restart my server or my docker container crashes? Then it doesn't work fine.

What is the best/conventional/standard way to keep my docker container running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an orchestrator. An orchestrator will manage your container life cycle for you. You might want to try the Docker orchestrator, Swarm. You can also check Kubernetes or Mesos.

You could also use Docker compose to make things easier.

Comment: I'll take a look at Swarm.

Do you have the exact commands for running the 'example' in the question in Swarm?

Comment: I would recommend you to read the Swarm Tutorial : https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/

You will have to do a few commands first, like swarm init or service create, but the documentation is pretty clear and straightforward

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will use Swarm for the long term benefit of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

As @wassim-dif pointed out you might want to use an orchestrator.

If you just want your docker container to restart automatically in case of failure and when you restart your server then you need to run it using the --restart flag, such as:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -td --restart=always example
```

This way, your container will restart automatically.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. It looks like a easy solution, restarting it when my server restarts.

I'll actually take a look at Docker compose as I am quite new to docker as well.